# Least Squares of Symmetric Positive Semidefinite Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, positive-semidefinite

What's the best (in terms of computation time and numerical robustness) way to find the least squares solution of $$Ax = b$$ if $A$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite?

If $A$ were symmetric and *positive definite*, the Cholesky decomposition would seem to be the way to go to build the inverse.  But that doesn't work for positive semidefinite cases.

Performing a [spectral decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices) to get $A = Q \Lambda Q^T$, and then forming the pseudoinverse $A^+ = Q \Lambda^+ Q^T$ to get $x = A^+ b$ works, but I'm not convinced it's the most efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MATLAB's [`mldivide()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html):

[image]

If the [Cholesky Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) doesn't work you should use [LDL Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition_2).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good break down and what I did in the end.